# cycle through characters in vim

Tags: vim, unicode, macros, character

I would like to create a vim macro to do next:

if I type the character "a", "e", "o", "i" or "u" and press a shorctut key p.e. F12 
it has to cycle through characters every time I click the shortcut key

p.e.

a -> F12 -> à -> F12 -> â -> F12 -> ä -> F12 -> ä -> F12 -> back to "a" again
A -> F12 -> À -> F12 -> Â -> F12 -> Ä -> F12 -> Ä -> F12 -> back to "A" again

same for
e --> eéèêëée
E --> EÉÊÈËÉE
i --> iîïi
I --> IÎÏI
o --> oôöo
O --> OÔÖO
u --> uûùüüu
U --> UÛÙÜU

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to achieve this. You can use CTRL-a in command mode to increase the character code, but that's not what you wanted.

Comment: You could probably adapt [unicycle.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1384) to handle these, although I could have sworn there was another plugin dedicated to this already.  I can't find it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function which does what you want. It works by grabbing the unicode character under the cursor, seeing if it exists in a one of the lists of characters, and if so advancing it to the next character in that list. I grab the character under the cursor in an ugly way by copying it, extracting it from the register, and then restoring the register's original contents at the end of the function. There must be a more elegant way!

```
function! CycleThroughChars()
    let x_contents = getreg("x")
    let x_type = getregtype("x")
    let lists = [ ["a","à","â","ä","a"],
                \ ["A","À","Â","Ä","A"],
                \ ["e","é","è","ê","ë","e"],
                \ ["E","É","Ê","È","Ë","E"],
                \ ["i","î","ï","i"],
                \ ["I","Î","Ï","I"],
                \ ["o","ô","ö","o"],
                \ ["O","Ô","Ö","O"],
                \ ["u","û","ù","ü","u"],
                \ ["U","Û","Ù","Ü","U"] ]
    sil exe 'normal! "xyl'
    let c_char = @x
    for this_list in lists
        let c_index = index(this_list,c_char)
        if c_index != -1
            sil exe "normal! r" . this_list[c_index+1]
            break
        endif
    endfor
    call setreg("x",x_contents,x_type)
    startinsert
endfunction
inoremap <silent> <F12> <ESC>:call CycleThroughChars()<CR><right>
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I realised the second for loop was redundant, so I have removed it from the function. The functionality is unaffected, but only one `index()` call is necessary per list.

Comment: I spent way too long trying to come up with an answer to this and mine ended up being quite a bit more sloppy than this when it was done.  Great job (untested ;))

Comment: `let @x` and `old_paste_contents` should be modified with `getreg()`, `getregtype()` and `setreg()` instead. This way you don't lose register type (rectangular, lines, or characterwise).

Comment: Thanks Benoit, I have made those changes. Useful advice.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash, I noted that you function doesn't work in utf8 encoding. Do you know what to change to let it work? It is a multibyte problem isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I was able to replace the supplemental function with a call to matchstr().  This is a little cleaner now than it was.

For completeness, here was what I came up with.

```
let g:unicode_list = [
\    [ 'a', 'à', 'â', 'ä' ],
\    [ 'A', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä' ],
\    [ 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ê', 'ë' ],
\    [ 'E', 'É', 'Ê', 'È', 'Ë' ],
\    [ 'i', 'î' ], 
\    [ 'I', 'Î', 'Ï' ],
\    [ 'o', 'ô', 'ö' ],
\    [ 'O', 'Ô', 'Ö' ],
\    [ 'u', 'û', 'ù', 'ü' ],
\    [ 'U', 'Û', 'Ù', 'Ü' ],
\]

function! CycleUnicode(mode)
    let char = matchstr(getline('.'), '.', col('.')-1)
    for sublist in g:unicode_list
        let idx = index(sublist, char)
        if idx >= 0
            try
                let char = sublist[idx+1]
            catch /E684/
                let char = sublist[0]
            endtry
            execute "normal! r" . char
            break 
        endif
    endfor
    if a:mode == 'i'
        startinsert
    endif
endfunction

inoremap <f12> <esc>:call CycleUnicode('i')<enter><right>
nnoremap <f12> :call CycleUnicode('n')<enter>
```

Comment: We were thinking along the same lines! The toughest part is extracting the unicode character under the cursor... it seems odd that Vim doesn't have a native way of doing that.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash You may be interested in the edit I just made.  I think I've found a way to get the character much more cleanly than I had before.  Good reference material for the future anyway.

Comment: @RandyMorris, Your function doesn't work either with unicode characters if encoding is utf-8